# Constructing a determinantal inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant, block-matrices

The following is from page 3410 of the paper [Quadratically constrained attitude control via semidefinite programming](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/CDC.2003.1271671).

Consider a polynomial:

$$\mu_1(p_1^Tx)^2+ \cdots + \mu_n(p_n^Tx)^2\leq a$$

where

1. $x\in R^n$, $p_i\in R^n$
2. $\mu_i,a\in R_+$

Can that polynomial assume the following?

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}I_n & l(x) \\l(x)^T & a \end{bmatrix}\geq 0$$
where $$l(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{\mu_1}p_1^Tx  \\\vdots \\ \sqrt{\mu_n}p_n^Tx   \end{bmatrix}$$.

---

I try to derive from the following:

1. determinant:   From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant
   $\text{det}(A) = \text{det}(I_na)-\text{det}(l(x)l(x)^T) = a$ since $l(x)l(x)^T$ is rank $1$ so there must exist eigenvalue $0$; therefore, $\text{det}(l(x)l(x)^T)=0$.     Not correct.

How to show both are equivalent?

Comment: Where's the LMI?

Comment: Are the $\mu_i$ positive?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo   LMI is $A\geq 0$ or $A\leq 0$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, all positive

Comment: Then why did you write $\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}$? Also, an inequality of the form $\det(A) \geq 0$ is **not** an LMI.

Comment: You're using the wrong formula for the determinant of a block matrix. You can get unstuck using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu_i > 0$,

$$\mu_1 (\mathrm{p}_1^T \mathrm{x})^2 + \mu_2 (\mathrm{p}_2^T \mathrm{x})^2 + \cdots + \mu_n (\mathrm{p}_n^T \mathrm{x})^2 = \| (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} P^T \mathrm{x}\|_2^2$$

where the $i$-th column of $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is $\mathrm{p}_i$. The polynomial inequality

$$\mu_1 (\mathrm{p}_1^T \mathrm{x})^2 + \mu_2 (\mathrm{p}_2^T \mathrm{x})^2 + \cdots + \mu_n (\mathrm{p}_n^T \mathrm{x})^2 \leq a$$

can then be written as the following **determinantal inequality**

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} I_n & (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} P^T \mathrm{x}\\ \mathrm{x}^T P (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} & a\end{bmatrix} \geq 0$$

as the determinant of the block matrix above is

$$\begin{array}{rl}\det \begin{bmatrix} I_n & (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} P^T \mathrm{x}\\ \mathrm{x}^T P (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} & a\end{bmatrix} &= a - \mathrm{x}^T P (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} P^T \mathrm{x}\\\\ &= a - \| (\operatorname{diag}(\mu))^{\frac{1}{2}} P^T \mathrm{x} \|_2^2\end{array}$$